# JSF 2 + Spring 3 can't access bean

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I'm trying to use Spring 3 along with JSF 2, but I'm already having trouble doing the following :

```
<h:outputText value="#{sampleController.hello}" />
```

Using a static value works just fine but getting the value from Java doesn't (it doesn't display anything) e.g.

```
<body>
    Test <h:outputText value="#{sampleController.hello}" /> <h:outputText value="hello" />
</body>
```

Would show up as

> Test hello

SampleController.java :

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SampleController {

    private String hello = "Hello!";

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

}
```

I used "JSF 2 + Spring 3 Integration" from Mkyong for the project configuration (http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/)

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="eu.shishigami" />

    <context:annotation-config />

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>Sample</display-name>

    <!-- Add Support for Spring -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.WebAppRootListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- JSF Mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: Remember to use `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` tags instead of `<head>` and `<body>`. Not sure if this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it accordingly. Sadly it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Try adding the `@ManagedBean` annotation to your `SampleController` class.

Comment: No luck with that either, unfortunately. I also tried @Named as suggested in 3.3 @ mkyong but that didn't work either.

Comment: I've been able to get it to work on another PC. It's literally exaclty the same (I copied everything from this thread) but it works... owell.

Comment: Maybe is a configuration problem in your first working environment. Note that those problems are hard to detect from code fragments only.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the servlet-mapping jsf, this is for 1.2 version. Without the servlet-mapping works!

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```